# Take Proxy Credentials from User from NPAPI Plugin

Tags: winapi, proxy, npapi, wininet

I have a NPAPI Plugin (Windows/Win32) that downloads a zip file from the server.
It does not work if the client in behind a proxy.
How would I get the proxy credentials from the user through my NPAPI Plugin?
I used HttpQueryInfo to detect presence of proxy by querying its status. If "407" is returned i use InternetErrorDlg to get credentials from the user but Chrome(29.0.1547.66 m) crashes on encountering the line. FF(19.0.2) works good.

Are there any more ways to do this ? Prompt the user to enter proxy credentials?
Any help in this regard will greatly be appreciated.

With Lots of Thanks,
LazyCoder7.

Comment: what are you using to do the download? NPN_GetURL?

Comment: I have Windows, Mac and Linux version of this plugin and for each of the platform I use the NativeCode. For Win32 i use InternetOpenUrl, HttpQueryInfo and InternetReadFileFunctions to download the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the browser APIs to download then the proxy should Just Work(tm).  The way you're doing it you can probably use [NPN_GetValueForURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_GetValueForURL) to get proxy information on newer browsers; barring that you need to remember that you aren't allowed to block the main thread, which is probably what you're doing that causes it to crash.  Get the credentials using HTML or something and then pass them in; it is possible to use windows dialogs to do it as long as you use another thread and are careful, but it's much easier to handle it in javascript/html.

Comment: Thanks Taxillan, I too was thinking for the same thing to just hit a URl and check the presence of proxy take the credentials from Html itself and pass on to the plugin.

Comment: Also i will check the part you mentioned "Not to block main thread" I will try to invoke a dialog for another thread. I didn't hit this thing while coding. A big Thanks for this point.

Comment: Lastly during initial stages of development i had used NPN_GETURL to download the file. But during that time I faced some problems like that it retrieved the file from CACHE if present. This was not desirable. I didn't get around this problem and many others were there i don't remember. So was then forced to used Native API's available for the respective platforms.

Comment: @LazyCoder7, with plugins running out-of-process, browsers need to employ hacks to see when you run modal dialogs on the main thread to know when they should spin their own event loops in the main process and not kill your plugin for hanging. That's fragile and different browsers cover different dialog types... as you found out between Firefox and Chrome here. The best thing really is not to do it - covering this in the website and passing information to the plugin is definitely the most reliable way here. Bonus - it's platform-independent.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche, Thanks for the tip. Yes, I will follow the way suggested by you and also mentioned by taxillian. It would be a really versatile solution rather then fiddling around with message loops.

Comment: And i was just curious to know that whether there exists a solution to NPN_GETURL not download from the file already present in cache and ALWAYS get the resource from the server ?

Comment: You could probably hack it by adding some sort of querystring (a timestamp is traditional), e.g. http://myhost.com/something.zip?ts=1378479679781 but I don't know of any other way

Comment: @LazyCoder7 Can you fix the [server side](http://serverfault.com/questions/256558/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-client-browser-caching-for-specific-websites) (`"Cache-Control"`)?